# is it safe to update to 2019-02 win10 ver1803 KB4346084?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My dell 14 inspiron 7460 recently has prompt me for updating to version KB4346084, which I hesitate since I heard about all the disaster after new win10 updates.

I google for it and it didn't show much problem on it, except this one: https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/after-kb4346084-computer-wakes-from-sleep-with-magnifier-locked-up.185368/
, is it recommended to update or stay at my current version 17134.706?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My dell 14 Inspiron 7460 recently has prompt me for updating to version KB4346084, which I hesitate since I heard about all the disaster after new win10 updates.

`KB4346084`is an optional security update that should absolutely be installed if you have one of the affected products.  Since it is not a cumulative update your build number will not changed and remaine at `17134.706`.

> is it recommended to update or stay at my current version 17134.706?

Since it is not a cumulative update your build would not be changed.  **The current 1803 build actually is 17134.706**